# Angular 6 - Parsing JSON

Tags: json, angular, asp.net-core-webapi

I'm having trouble with a .net core SPA app.
- Results are being passed back by the API call
- the SPA is not handling the results.

here is the pertinent code:

SPA ts:

```
class TestLibraryItem {
  private _apiPath: string;
  private _http: HttpClient;

  public name: string;
  public testResults: TestResult;

  constructor(name: string, apiPath: string, http: HttpClient) {
    this.name = name;
    this._apiPath = apiPath;
    this._http = http;
  }

  RunTests() {
    this._http.get<TestResult>(this._apiPath)
      .subscribe(result => {
      this.testResults = result;
      console.log(this.testResults);
      console.log(this.testResults.CheckName);
    });
  }
}

class TestResult {
  CheckName: string;
  Checks: CheckResult[];
}

class CheckResult {
  Test: string;
  Pass: boolean;
}
```

and the console results when RunTests() is fired:

```
{"CheckName":"Check One","Checks":[{"Test":"Test one","Pass":true},{"Test":"Test two","Pass":true}]}
undefined
```

As far as I can tell, I'm getting valid json back from the API (indicated by console.log spitting it out, but it is not actually building the object which results in the undefined.

Answer (score 1):

I think your properties in the *JSON* are parsed from upper case to lower case - `CheckName -> checkName`. As Javascript/Typescript is a case sensitive language you need to different property names.

Try to log with lower case and also change your property names to start with lower case. It is a common standard in `Javascript/Typescript` to start function and variable/property names via lower case.

```
console.log(this.testResults.checkName);
```

Answer (score 1):

You are getting undefined because this console.log(this.testResults) is fired first

```
RunTests() {
    this._http.get<TestResult>(this._apiPath)
      .subscribe(result => {
      this.testResults = result;
      console.log(this.testResults);
      console.log(this.testResults.CheckName === undefined ? '' : this.testResults['CheckName']);
    });
  }
```

or use SetTimeOut

```
 RunTests() {
        this._http.get<TestResult>(this._apiPath)
          .subscribe(result => {
          this.testResults = result;
          console.log(this.testResults);
         setTimeout(()=>{console.log(this.testResults['CheckName'])},2000); 

        });
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue i.e. it looked lika valid json response but in fact it was a "text" response. Give the following a try:

```
  getdData(inParams) {
    let headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers = headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');

    // need responseType = text (non object)
    return this.http.get(environment.url, {
      headers,
      responseType: 'text'
    });
  }
```